# How to add a folder to Android resources

Tags: android

I have a few thousand image files in a directory structure. There are a few hundred different subdirectories and each directory contains 10 images named 1.png - 10.png...

How can I add these folders to my app and access these images? Assuming I want foo/bar/1.png?

In android it doesn't appear like you have a string path to your assets or raw directories so I have no clue how I would do this. Please don't tell me I have to zip them then unzip them out of assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In android it doesn't appear like you have a string path to your assets

Sure you do. `getAssets().open("foo/bar/1.png")` will give you an `InputStream` to that PNG file, assuming that your project has `assets/foo/bar/1.png` in it. You can then use `BitmapFactory` to read it in.

However, resources cannot exist in subdirectories. You could write a script on your development machine that flattens the structure (e.g., `foo/bar/1.png` into `foo_bar_1.png`), then put the renamed files into whichever `res/drawable-NNNN/` directory is appropriate.

Comment: Dragging folder foo into assets and setting link to folders causes the file not to be found. Dragging the folder and selecting copy to project works. Dragging the folder and link + virtual folders doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark: Correct. The files have to be in your `assets/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

the path to access the android asset folder is :

```
file:///android_asset/filename
```

You should be able to access a folder with :

```
file:///android_asset/folder1/folder2/targetFolder/
```

Note that there is 3 '**/**' after '**file:**'

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/1.png"); doesn't work and neither does using the folders. getAssets().open("1.png") does work.